# Save a Bitmap that is concived through Storage file to a file WITHOUT a stream (UWP, Drag and Drop)

Tags: c#, image, uwp, drag-and-drop, bitmapimage

in my application i get images dropped that are being displayed as an XAML Controls Image, these Images come in via the 'Drop' action as Storage Items. Now i need to save these images to a file (doesn't really matter where or as what format(png, jpg etc). Because i only need to save these because i need to get them from a file location for an upload. But all solutions i found use some sort of Stream. Now if it is possible to get that from Storage Items or a Bitmap i don't know how to do that and found nothing i saw fit.
Is there a way to get that as a stram?
Or is there another way to save Images from the Startpoint of StorageItem, Bitmap or XAML Controls Image?

Here is the start of my code for the Drop event:

```
private async void Galerie_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
            {
                var Items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();

                foreach (StorageFile storageItem in Items)
                {
                    BitmapImage DroppedImages = new BitmapImage();
                    DroppedImages.SetSource(await storageItem.OpenReadAsync());

                    ...
                    ...
                }
            }
         }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, from your problem description, are you trying to drag and drop a group of image files into the application, then display these images on the interface, and upload these images later. If so, when reading `e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync()`, you can try to keep the `StorageFile` reference, such as creating a `List<StorageFile>`, and adding the read file to the list during for-each loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes that is what i am doing.                 If i keep the ```StorageFile``` around what can i do with that to save the images to a file somewhere? or can i generate a stream from the storage files somehow?               Thank you

Comment: Hello, which type of the Stream you need? Is `IRandomAccessStream` or other types? If you want to save a image to a file, what is the source of the image? Is the image data (`byte[]`) or from the Image control or `BitmapImage`?

Comment: I think ```IRandomAccessStream``` is what i need to save an image to a file yes. The source of the image is a drag and drop event, which is why i don't get a Stream :/. The image comes as a ```StorageFile``` and i convert it to a ```BitmapImage```.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your needs, but in the `Galerie_Drop` method, you have already obtained `StorageFile` (the **storageItem** in the loop), if you need `IRandomAccessStream`, then just use `await storageItem.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);` You can get the stream of the file, then you can upload it or do other things.

Comment: Oh thank you i'll try that